# Updating a table with a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables related `program` and `formation`. Here are the scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `camstaf`.`program` (
  `id_program` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `terms` TEXT NULL,
  `objectives` TEXT NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'type: séminaire ou certification',
  `period_min` DATE NULL,
  `period_max` DATE NULL,
  `duration` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `budget` TEXT NULL,
  `precision_budget` TEXT NULL,
  `achieved` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_program`))
ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `camstaf`.`formation` (
  `id_formation` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `terms` TEXT NULL,
  `objectifs` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `date_start` DATE NULL,
  `date_end` DATE NULL,
  `direct_costs` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `ind_costs` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `precision_couts` TEXT NULL,
  `scheduled_training` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `status` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_formation`),
  INDEX `fk_fk_formation_match_program_idx` (`scheduled_training` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fk_formation_match_program`
    FOREIGN KEY (`scheduled_training`)
    REFERENCES `camstaf`.`program` (`id_program`)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

I want the table `program` to be updated with this trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `camstaf`.`formation_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `formation` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.scheduled_training != NULL THEN
        UPDATE program
        SET achieved = TRUE
        WHERE id_program = NEW.scheduled_training AND achieved = FALSE;
    END IF;
END
```

But it doesn't work. I can't find wht's wrong. Any idea?!

Comment: "*But it doesn't work*" - that's the worst possible way to explain *how* your code isn't working. If you were to read this kind of question, what would you answer to the person asking? Would you ask *HOW* is the code not working? How did you run this SQL? From MySQL terminal, PHP script, some other program?

Comment: Rows (`program` table) are never updated, right?. `NEW.scheduled_training != NULL` -> `NULL` (`FALSE` will be evaluated), see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5wvuQno6HCy6dJKE9m7E8R/0). Check [3.3.4.6 Working with NULL Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html).

Comment: The if should likely be: `IF NEW.scheduled_training IS NOT NULL THEN`

Comment: thx for ur answer